# How to convert a number to a linked list in C++

Tags: c++

I am starting out learning about linked lists and am trying to solve a programming problem. The output needs to be a number represented as a linked list. For example, if the number is 123, the linked list needs to be 3->2->1.

According to my implementation, I am doing all other functions beforehand and have the final output number as an int, and need to convert it to a linked list. I tried the following code.

```
    ListNode* numToLL(int sum){

         ListNode* mainHead;
         int remainder = sum % 10;
         mainHead->val = remainder;
         sum = sum / 10;
         ListNode* head;
         head = mainHead;
         while (sum != 0){
             ListNode* nextNode;
             int remainder = sum % 10;            
             nextNode->val = remainder;
             head->next = nextNode;
             head = nextNode;
             sum = sum / 10;
         }
         return mainHead;
    }
```

I know this is incorrect, but I am not sure how to correct it. The error message for this says:  "runtime error: member access within null pointer of type 'struct ListNode'" on the 3rd line inside the function.

Comment: `ListNode* nextNode;` then `nextNode->val` you did not allocate memory for your node.

Comment: Read the error message. "null pointer of type struct ListNode". What do you think this means? Have you learned about pointers?

Comment: Input the number as a string.  Access each digit as `std::string[i]`.  If you need, convert digit to number:  `number = digit_string[i] - '0';`.  Insert digit into linked list.

Comment: Most linked lists allocate from dynamic memory using `new`.  Where are you allocating memory for nodes?  The `ListNode * nextNode` in the `while` loop only allocates a **pointer** not a node.  You'll need to review the chapter about pointers and dynamic memory in your favorite C++ reference.

Answer (score 1):

This should fix your current error, no guarantees there aren't other errors.  Do your own homework :)

Changing `ListNode* mainHead;` to `ListNode* mainHead = new ListNode();` will allocate memory for an instantiation of class type ListNode and return the memory address allocated to the pointer variable you declared.

Without this change your mainHead variable contains an unknown value that could potentially point to anything.  Judging by your error it contains the same value as NULL, but this isn't guaranteed.

Same thing goes for `ListNode* nextNode;` -> `ListNode* nextNode = new ListNode();`

```
ListNode* numToLL(int sum){
     ListNode* mainHead = new ListNode();
     int remainder = sum % 10;
     mainHead->val = remainder;
     sum = sum / 10;
     ListNode* head;
     head = mainHead;
     while (sum != 0){
         ListNode* nextNode = new ListNode();
         int remainder = sum % 10;            
         nextNode->val = remainder;
         head->next = nextNode;
         head = nextNode;
         sum = sum / 10;
     }
     return mainHead;
}
```

Comment: Don't post only code answers.  Illustrate, or explain, how your code differs from the OP's and how it resolves the issue.

Answer (score 1):

`mainHead` and `nextNode` are both uninitialized.  You are not allocating valid `ListNode` objects for them to point at before accessing their `val` fields.

Also, you are repeating the same code above and inside your loop.  It is a good idea to follow the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) ("Don't repeat yourself") when writing code, it makes for easier maintenance over time.

A common idiom for populating a linked list in a loop without repeating code is to use an extra level of indirection - a pointer to the *next* `ListNode*` pointer that is waiting to be allocated.  For example:

```
ListNode* numToLL(int sum)
{
    ListNode* theList = NULL;
    ListNode** node = &theList;
    do
    {
        *node = new ListNode;
        (*node)->val = sum % 10;
        (*node)->next = NULL;
        node = &((*node)->next);
        sum /= 10;
    }
    while (sum != 0);
    return theList;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/uJlQwz)